# How Apache Spark collects and coordinate the results from executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, executor

Posting this question to learn how Apache Spark collects and coordinate the results from executors.

Suppose I'm running a job with 3 executors. My DataFrame is partitioned and running across these 3 executors. 
So now, When I execute a count() or collect() action on the DataFrame how spark will coordinate the results from these 3 executors?

```
val prods = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("testFile.csv")

prods.count(); // How spark collect data from three executors? Who will coordinate the result from different executors and give it to driver?
```

Answer (score 1):

prods.count(); // How spark collect data from three executors? Who will coordinate the result from different executors and give it to driver?

When you do spark-submit you specify master a client program (driver) starts running on yarn ,if yarn is specified master or local if local specified. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Since you have added tag yarn in the question i am assuming you mean yarn-url,so yarn launches client program(driver) on any of the nodes of cluster and registers and assigns workers (executors) to driver so that task to be executed on each node.Each transformation/action is run parallel on each worker nodes (executor).Once each node complete the job they return back there results to the driver program.

Comment: Hi tarun; Thanks for the effort. I know about yarn and how it allocates resources for spark application. But that's not the answer I want. I will remove the yarn tag from the question if it's made any confusions.

Answer (score 1):

Oki,what part are you not clear ?

Let me make it generic,the client/driver program launches and requests the master local/standalone master/yarn aka Cluster Manager that driver program wants resources to perform tasks ,so allocate driver with the workers for that.The cluster manager in return allocates workers,launches executors on worker nodes and gives the information to client program that you can you use these workers to do your job.So data is divided in each worker node and parallel tasks/transformations are done.Once collect() or count() is called (i assume this is the final part of job).Then each executor return its result back to driver.

Comment: Okay executor return its result back to the driver. Agreed. So who will coordinate the result. As I have 3 executors, Whose job it is to sum up `count` received from each executors

Comment: The executors process the task and the result sends back to the driver through the cluster manager.It is job of each each worker to sump there partition data and return the result to driver.https://data-flair.training/blogs/how-apache-spark-works/. You can also have a go through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49Hr5xZyTEA&t=317s

Comment: As you said each partition will sum up its on data, Say executor-1 has 15 rows of data, executor-2 has 10 and executor-3 has 25. So finally when I execute count action I will get 50 as an output. I know that executors sends the results data to the driver. So to show 50 as an output some program/service has to sumup the results from executor-1, 2 and 3. Who will do that part?